# Is cygwin needed for rtools 35

Tags: r, cygwin, rtools

I'm trying to compile the `r` package `stringi` on my Win10 machine. First I struggled with `Rtools` not beeing detected by `Rstudio` but thanks to the answer of [Rtools 3.5 not recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182443/rtools-3-5-not-recognized) I was able to fix that.
However it sill does not compile and gives me the error:

```
C:\Rtools\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected
```

mentioning it was propably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Now in the `Rtools.txt`(https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/installer.html) it is mentioned that `cygwin` is not used anymore.

I'm a bit confused now since installing cygwin (both x86 and x86_64) does not solve the problem. Any advice is much appreciated.

I'm using `R 3.5.1` and `Rtools 3.5` on a Windows 10 64 Bit machine.

Comment: ["Our toolset contains copies of Cygwin DLLs that may conflict with other ones on your system if both are in the path at once. The normal recommendation is to delete the older ones; however, at one time we found our tools did not work with a newer version of the Cygwin DLLs, so it may be safest not to have any other version of the Cygwin DLLs in your path. "](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) Do, you have cygwin in your path? Do you have different msys2 versions in your path?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. In my path I neither have cygwin nor any msys2. I'm now trying to uninstall cygwin (both versions) again.

Comment: OK this did, as expected, not change anything. Do I get this right, that I don't have to install `mingw` or `msys2`?

Comment: If you install Rtools correctly, you don't have to install anything else.

Comment: I now updated Rstudio and reinstalled Rtools. However the error remains.

Comment: I still suspect you have something else on your system interfering. For example, some people have reported this error message after Adobe Flash Player updates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46830325/1412059

Comment: Something like this could very well be. However I am not able to check this since this is a company's laptop where I am not allowed to install / unistall software.